# sensations as meditation object

Tags: vipassana

Can sensations be a meditation object like breath? if yes how do I practice meditations with it?

Answer (score 1):

Vedananupassana (contemplation of feelings) is part of the [Satipatthana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satipatthana). There are 3 types of feelings:

1. Pleasant feeling or sensation,
2. Unpleasant feeling or sensation,
3. Neutral feeling or sensation.

In Vedananupassana you focus your mind on the sensation to see how and when it arises and how and when it passes away, keeping your mind steadfastly equanimous without getting attached to the pleasant sensations or averse to the painful sensation or ignorant of the transient nature of the neutral sensations.

This is a very concise description of the technique. It is best you take a course to learn it properly. Following are some pointers:

- https://www.dhamma.org/en/index
- http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/global/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, anything that is experienced can be an object like thoughts, seeing, hearing and the detection of bodily sensations.

Moment by moment the sensations can be  witnessed  in the body and the reactions to those sensations are witnessed in the mind.

At the moment there is witnessing(mindfulness) there can't be reactions.

Reactions are put into 3 categories:

> Disliking, anger, sadness, fear & in general, a pushing of the sensation away from being experienced more.
>
> Liking, greed, attraction & in general, a pulling of the sensation towards being experienced more.
>
> Neither pushing the sensations away or pulling the sensations towards what is being experienced.